# Concat folder/subfolder file of type X contents to variable

Tags: macos, bash

Im trying to write a script that:

1. Reads a single file to a variable
2. Iterates through all files in all subfolders of a type and adds their contents to that same variable

I had tried this path.

```
    common_css=$(cat "$path/normalize.css") #$path is valid
    find $path/common -type f -name *.css | while read f; do
        common_css=$common_css $(cat "$f")
        echo "$common_css"
    done

    echo "$common_css"
```

EX:

```
FILES
/normalize.css = body{ background-color : red; }
/common/name.css = table{ display : block; }
/common/oauth.conf = key="somekey"
/common/place.css = p{ font-size: 2em; }

DESIRED OUTPUT
body{ background-color : red; }
table{ display : block; }
p{ font-size: 2em; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (assuming you really want to build up the entire string in memory):

```
common_css=$(cat "$path/normalize.css"; 
             find "$path/common" -type f -name '*.css' -exec cat {} +)
```

- A single command substitution can output the concatenation of the contents of all files of interest, no need for loops.

  - `-exec cat {} +`, thanks to the trailing `+`, passes as many matching file paths as will fit onto a single command line to `cat`, resulting in typically just *one* invocation.
- I've added quoting to make the command more robust - notably, you should always quote the glob argument passed to `-name`, to prevent premature expansion by the shell.